# Unable to change language Rails? (Spree)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, rails-i18n

For some reason, I can't seem to change the language of a Rails website.

I've got a /config/locales/en.yml and a /config/locales/nl.yml. In application.rb, I've tried different things, right now it's:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
config.i18n.available_locales = [:nl, :en, "nl", "en"]
config.i18n.locale = :nl
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true
config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false
I18n.locale = :nl
```

However, I've tried :'nl' as well. The '[:nl, "nl"]' is just there because I found both in solutions, but none worked for me. The website uses Spree (2.3), and I use the Spree.t() function to translate. When I just change the text in the en.yml file - which is the default language loaded - it does change the text on the site.

Comment: In what context do you want to change ? once and for all in the application.rb => remember to restart your server ? Or dynamically in the controller with some params[:locale] and therefore using I18n.locale =... coupled with a before_action... ?

Comment: @charlysisto I do want to change it once and for all, and I've changed the application.rb. I've also restarted the server, without any luck... :(

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, was adding the following lines to `config/initializers/spree.rb`:

```
    Spree::Frontend::Config[:locale] = :nl
    Spree::Backend::Config[:locale] = :en
```